# Getting ip adress on win 7 and XP

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need the batch file to check if the ip address is blank or missing.  Some times the batch file will be ran on windows 7 and sometimes on windows xp. so i need this kind of output.

if not missing or blank
"your ip is %ip%, Everything is ok

if missing or blank
"Error No ip found"

```
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : dxtnxx.naits.local
IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 11.73.11.111
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.254.0
IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : fe80::21b:77ff:fec3:f95b%5
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.11.11.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal
for /f "tokens=2delims=[]" %%a in ('ping -n 1 -4 %computername% ^| find /i "%computername%"') do set "ip=%%a"
if "%ip%"=="127.0.0.1" set "ip="
if not defined ip (echo.Error No ip found) else echo.your ip is %ip%, Everything is ok
endlocal
```

Comment: you should find "IPv4" instead of "IP" in Line 2. Just in Case IPv6 is configured too.

Comment: Thank you. Testing now first for `IPv4` and after that for `IP` (for XP).

Comment: It would also be worthwhile to test that the IP doesn't begin with `169.254`, as that's a non-functional autoconfig IP that Windows assigns itself when it can't contact a DHCP server.

Comment: Nevertheless, it's a valid IP.

Comment: While this seems to work... as it dont shut it down like the issue i had when i tried.. I get "your ip is fe80"  What i think might be happening is its getting more then the first result?  any idea?

Comment: iam currently using windows xp,  i ask for windows 7 as the computers are going to be upgraded soon... but ill post my ipconfig from there

Comment: added, though i did change some of the numbers in ip

Comment: ok with first one, it will detect ip in a valid setup,  if setup is invalid it will say "fe80  Everything is ok"   not sure what this fe80 is or if it will even show up in a real test but i will try it here shortly...  the second one passes the valid test but when running invalid test it will say 127.0.0.1  everything is ok

Comment: `127.0.0.1`is a predefined localhost address, I modifyed the second code and will look into the first.

Comment: In the output from `ipconfig` have all lines only a `CR` on the end, no `LF` in the whole text. So I can't parse that & removed the code from my answer. I improved the other code slightly and added the parameter `/i` to the find command.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims={}" %%I in (
    'wmic nicconfig where ipenabled^="TRUE" get ipaddress /format:list'
) do set "ip=%%~I"

if "%ip:~0,7%" equ "169.254" set ip=
if "%ip:~0,2%" equ "0." set ip=

if not defined ip (
    echo Error: No Internet access.
    exit /b 1
)
echo Your IP address is %ip%.  We're good to go.
```

As mfm4aa points out, this script will not work with XP Home, as XP Home doesn't include `wmic`.  XP Pro should be fine, though.

Besides checking whether or not the machine has an IP address, this script will also check whether the IP address is a `169.254` autoconfig address and fail accordingly.

Comment: `wmic` is NOT includet in all XP versions. Your code will fail in this cases.

Comment: @mfm4aa - Oh?  I didn't know that.  Yeah, I [see now](http://people.virginia.edu/~rtg2t/winadmin/wmic.html) that `wmic` isn't included with XP Home.

Comment: When valid , it does work .. shows ip but when not valid i get your ip is 0.0.0.0. ...passed.

Comment: @GlenMorse - I think perhaps in that case the IP actually is being reported by `wmic` as 0.0.0.0.  We can work around that with another `if` statement.  Try the updated code, please.

Comment: it will work if ip address is valid, but when not valid it now closes out of the cmd screen.

Comment: @GlenMorse - Seriously? It took more effort for you to compose that comment than it would have for you to remove the `exit /b` or replace it with a `pause` or whatever else would've been appropriate.  I'm more than willing to help you, but henceforth the amount of effort I give you will be equal to the effort you put forth yourself.  If you want all the work done for you so you don't have to think for yourself, then [mfm4aa is your man](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541346/getting-ip-adress-on-win-7-and-xp/15548311?noredirect=1#15544811).

Comment: Or I all ready had a pause in there. And it has jumped out when ever there is a problem. And never asked for an exit. So never looked. But thanks anyhow....